# Condensing Left Join Result Set into one row

Tags: t-sql

I have a sql query which currently, due to a couple of Left joins, returns multiple rows:-

> Id
>   Action
>   Group

12345 NULL NULL

12345 ADD NULL

12345 NULL ABC Group

How do I go about condensing these 3 rows into one e.g.
12345 ADD ABC Group

Comment: Please provide query, data structure and what database you are using

Comment: All sorted thanks to Robert Sievers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints of your question are a bit unclear.  If for every ID, there is only one possible non-NULL value of the other columns, you could use MIN or MAX to pull those values out.  For example, put the query with the LEFT JOINS into a CTE, then do

```
SELECT ID, MAX(col2),MAX(col3)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

If there is the potential for multiple non-NULL values per column, you will need to be more specific about what you would want the output to look like.

Comment: That worked great thank you - just couldn't recall the approach to follow - Common Table Expression was the way to go